# How do I write down a curve with exactly one rational point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, rational-numbers

Let $g\geq 1$. I would like to write down (for all $g$) a smooth projective geometrically connected curve $X$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ of genus $g$ with precisely one rational point.

Is this possible?

For which $g$ is this possible?

I think for $g=1$ this is possible. I just don't know an explicit equation, but I should be able to find it. (We just write down an elliptic curve without torsion of rank zero over $\mathbf{Q}$.)

For $g\geq 2$ things get more complicated for me.

I would really like the curve to be of gonality at least $4$, but I'll think about that later.

Comment: What is $g$ supposed to have to do with the curve?

Comment: That would be the genus.

Comment: Dear Harry, what do you mean by "curve" and "genus" ?

Comment: Curve = smooth projective geometrically connected curve over $\mathbf{Q}$. The genus is the arithmetic genus (or geometric genus because of our definition of curves).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smooth plane projective  curve $E$ defined  over $\mathbb Q$ by the equation $y^2z=x^3+2z^3$ has its point at infinity $[0:1:0]$ as its only rational point: $E(\mathbb Q)=\lbrace [0:1:0]\rbrace $. Indeed:

a)  The torsion group of the curve $y^2z=x^3+az^3 $ is  zero  as soon as $a$ is a sixth-power free integer which is neither a square nor a cube nor equal to $-432$.
(Despite appearences I'm not making this crazy theorem up,  but I am quoting theorem (3.3) of Chapter 1 in Husemöller's [*Elliptic Curves*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Elliptic_Curves.html?id=aMN_ygNDdVEC&redir_esc=y) !).

b) On the other hand the curve $E$ has rank $0$, which means that its group of rational points is  torsion (this is stated in the table following the theorem I just quoted).

The  two results  a) and b) prove the assertion in my introductory sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is the elliptic curve I was hinting at in my question. Do there exist similar examples in higher genus?

Comment: Dear Georges, I think I have an idea on how to get more curves with just one rational point. For $n\geq 1$, let $X_n$ be the curve given by $(y^2z)^n = x^{3n}+2z^{3n}$. This curve is singular at its only rational point $(0:1:0)$ if $n\geq 2$. Its normalization will probably have more rational points, so this won't work. But maybe this gives an idea on how to  construct non-trivial branched covers of $X_1 = E$ with just one rational point?

Comment: I forgot to say that $X_n \to E$ via $(x:y:z)\mapsto (x^n:y^n:z^n)$. The   fibre over the $\mathbf{Q}$-rational point $(0:1:0)$ contains the point $(0:1:0)$. Note that for $n>2$, this map is unramified over $(0:1:0)$. There is exactly one rational point on $X_n(\mathbf{Q})$, but there might be more on its normalization.

Comment: Hi Georges, I think your assertion b) is incorrect, as pointed out by Emiliano Ambrosi in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783724/7719). According to Table 2 following Theorem (3.3) of Husemoller's "Elliptic Curves", the elliptic curve $y^{2} = x^{3} + 2$ has rank $1$. However perhaps you can take $a = 6$ instead.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment, but I'm afraid that the answer of George is incorrect.
Indeed the equation has at least 2 solutions, namely $[0:1:0]$ and $[-1:-1:1]$

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is a class of curve that has a single rational point on it, it is an hyperbola given by (x^2 + A)/(B - x).
  The conditions to give a single rational point would be for B^2 + A = a prime number, e.g.  B= 6 A = 5 the rational point would be at (5, 30).
   The conditions for 2 rational points would be that B^2 + A = N, where N = pq, e.g. B = 114 A = 203, the ratioanl points are at (47, 36) and (113, 12972).

Hope that this may help you.

Comment: I don't think this works. Maybe you're writing down curves with only one integer point? In fact, any rational value for $x$ will give a value for $y$ which is a rational number. I think that the projective curve induced by your equation is  isomorphic to the projective line.

Answer (score -1):

Harry
  When x is rational, the y coordinates are not rational for the majority of the x values. 
   If you look at (x^2 + 5) mod (6 - x) the value is only 0, at x = 5; similarly for the other example (x^2 + 203) mod (114 -x) only as 0 at x = 47 and x = 113.  It is the same for larger numbers(100 of digits).